# python - source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, python-pptx

**I tried to find the mistake within my code but I couldn't and in addition I tried to use the command:"sed -i 's/\x0//g' filename" but nothing changed. Maybe someone can help me. Thank you in advance!**

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor



prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title                          # title = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout).shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]                    # subtitle =  prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout).placeholders[1]
title.text = "Hello, World!"                        # prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout).shapes.title.text = "Hello World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!" 
title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(59,89, 152)             
prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout).placeholders[1].text = "python-pptx was here!"


prs.save('test.pptx')´´´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solve the problem by declaring the file as utf-8. All you have to do is put this line at the beginning of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: No problem :) Unicode doesn't come up often, but when it does it can seriously ruin your day. It's a good idea to read up (google) about Unicode support in python and which versions support what 